# How to check if sql_safe_updates is on?

Tags: mysql

I know that sql_safe_updates can be set to either 1 or 0 by for example running

```
SET sql_safe_updates=1;
```

How can I check if it's already on in command line?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates'`

Answer (score 17):

Or...

```
select @@sql_safe_updates;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns output ON/OFF

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "sql_safe_updates";
```

[image]

The following query returns output 0/1

```
select @@sql_safe_updates;
```

[image]

output shows that the safe update mode is enabled or disabled now.

```
1 and ON for enabled.
0 and OFF for disabled
```